# How do I convert this functional component to a class

Tags: reactjs, class, redux, components, state

How do I convert this functional component to a class component? I want to use state instead of HOC. Here is an example of this code at codesandbox [https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-hypatia-t5beo?file=/src/App.js►958](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-hypatia-t5beo?file=/src/App.js%E2%96%BA958)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Heading1",
    description:
      "Heading 1 Good day, everyone! \nI have headers. For each title."
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Heading2",
    description:
      "Heading 2 Good day, everyone! I have headers. For each title."
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "Heading3",
    description:
      "Heading 3 Good day, everyone! \nI have headers. For each title."
  },
];
export default function App() {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="headings">
        {data.map((d, i) => (
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              setIndex(i);
            }}
          >
            {d.title}
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className="description">
        <div className="content">{data[index]["description"]}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I want to use state instead of HOC. So many questions please explain. The function component you posted is actually using state with `index`

Comment: Why would you need to convert to a class? Also did you try to convert it and have an issue somewhere? Obviously as you can see below, there are some who will be willing to just hand out code, but not many, and your question is likely to be downvoted and closed as low effort/low quality. If you're having trouble with a specific issue while converting, feel free to update and we can explain why and try to help, but we expect the effort to be shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your class component

CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-wildflower-yeqvd

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Heading1",
    description:
      "Heading 1 Good day, everyone! \nI have headers. For each title, I have a description. \nFor example, I want the text to change, when I click on heading 2, please pay attention to the example, https://ibb.co/8mCHK5y \nI want to know what is best to use for such purposes? react-router or something else? for example some npm package. And what if there are such examples or lessons on the Internet, please leave me a link"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Heading2",
    description:
      "Heading 2 Good day, everyone! I have headers. For each title, I have a description. For example, I want the text to change, when I click on heading 2, please pay attention to the example, https://ibb.co/8mCHK5y I want to know what is best to use for such purposes? react-router or something else? for example some npm package. And what if there are such examples or lessons on the Internet, please leave me a link"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "Heading3",
    description:
      "Heading 3 Good day, everyone! \nI have headers. For each title, I have a description. \nFor example, I want the text to change, when I click on heading 2, please pay attention to the example, https://ibb.co/8mCHK5y \nI want to know what is best to use for such purposes? react-router or something else? for example some npm package. And what if there are such examples or lessons on the Internet, please leave me a link"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: "Heading4",
    description:
      "Heading 4 Good day, everyone! \nI have headers. For each title, I have a description. \nFor example, I want the text to change, when I click on heading 2, please pay attention to the example, https://ibb.co/8mCHK5y \nI want to know what is best to use for such purposes? react-router or something else? for example some npm package. And what if there are such examples or lessons on the Internet, please leave me a link"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    title: "Heading5",
    description:
      "Heading 5 Good day, everyone! \nI have headers. For each title, I have a description. \nFor example, I want the text to change, when I click on heading 2, please pay attention to the example, https://ibb.co/8mCHK5y \nI want to know what is best to use for such purposes? react-router or something else? for example some npm package. And what if there are such examples or lessons on the Internet, please leave me a link"
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    title: "Heading6",
    description:
      "Heading 6 Good day, everyone! \nI have headers. For each title, I have a description. \nFor example, I want the text to change, when I click on heading 2, please pay attention to the example, https://ibb.co/8mCHK5y \nI want to know what is best to use for such purposes? react-router or something else? for example some npm package. And what if there are such examples or lessons on the Internet, please leave me a link"
  }
];

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    index: 0
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="headings">
          {data.map((d, i) => (
            <button
              onClick={() => {
                this.setState({index: i})
              }}
            >
              {d.title}
            </button>
          ))}
        </div>
        <div className="description">
          <div className="content">{data[this.state.index]["description"]}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: ["Not all questions can or should be answered here"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ohk, Thanks I will remember this thing for next time